# How to load image from csv file in tensorflow

Tags: csv, tensorflow

I have image save in 0.csv files.

The format is as picture below.
[image]

[image]

How can I read it to tensorflow?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Dataset input pipeline introduced in tensorflow 1.4:

https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#consuming_text_data

Here's the example from the developers guide (though you'll want to read through that guide, it's quite well written):

```
filenames = ["/var/data/file1.txt", "/var/data/file2.txt"]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)

# Use `Dataset.flat_map()` to transform each file as a separate nested dataset,
# and then concatenate their contents sequentially into a single "flat" dataset.
# * Skip the first line (header row).
# * Filter out lines beginning with "#" (comments).
dataset = dataset.flat_map(
    lambda filename: (
        tf.data.TextLineDataset(filename)
        .skip(1)
        .filter(lambda line: tf.not_equal(tf.substr(line, 0, 1), "#"))))
```

The Dataset preprocessing pipeline has a few nice advantages. Most of the functionality you'll need such as reading text records, shuffling, batching, etc. are reduced to one-liners. More importantly though, it forces you into writing your preprocessing pipeline in a good, modular, testable way. It takes a little bit to get used to the API, but it's time well spent.

Comment: My text has multi-line.
This method only read single row in my csv file.
How can I read whole row as images?

Comment: @RJ.Lo you've probably found the answer since this is 4 years old, but if anyone is visiting this page and needs to do the same, use numpy's reshape to turn a row/list into a square image (cube if RGB) https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html